# SimpleOnGestureListener doesn't detect onFling on SurfaceView (but does detect onDown)

Tags: java, android, gesture

`onDown` works fine, it's detected and the debug text appears in Log. The `onFling` however is never called, both in the emulator on the latest API and my phone on API 16 (no toast or debug message).

I've followed Google's example to the letter ([third example on this page](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)) and I don't think it's a fragmentation issue as it's not working on both a relatively old and a new API.

I've checked other related questions here, my `onDown` is returning `true` so it should propagate.

My `onTouchEvent`:

```
@Override 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Here's my SimpleOnGestureListener:

```
class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "GESTURE"; 

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) { 
        Log.d("DOWN", "CATCH");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "FLING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("DOWN", "CATCH");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any indications would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: This is in an extended `SurfaceView` if it makes any difference.

Comment: tried: return mDetector.onTouchEvent(event); ?

Comment: @pskink Thanks! That did it, (**not** what's shown on Developer.Google for some reason)

Comment: ok: you override onTouchEvent in a View, they override in an Activity...

Comment: @pskink Thanks, that will be why.